# SSE load/store memory transactions

Tags: c++, performance, sse, simd

There are two ways for memory-register interactions in use SSE intrinsics:

Intermediate pointers:

```
void f_sse(float *input, float *output, unsigned int n)
{
   _m128 *input_sse = reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(input);//Input intermediate pointer
   _m128 *output_sse = reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(output);//Output intermediate pointer
   _m128 s = _mm_set1_ps(0.1f);
   auto loop_size = n/4; 
   for(auto i=0; i<loop_size; ++i)
      output_sse[i] = _mm_add_ps(input_sse[i], s);
}
```

Explicit fetch/store:

```
void f_sse(float *input, float *output, unsigned int n)
{
   _m128 input_sse, output_sse, result;
   _m128 s = _mm_set1_ps(0.1f); 
   for(auto i=0; i<n; i+=4)
   {
      input_sse  = _mm_load_ps(input+i);
      result     = _mm_add_ps(input_sse, s);
      _mm_store_ps(output+i, result);
   }
}
```

What's the difference between mentioned approaches and which method is better in terms of perfomance? input and output pointers are aligned by _mm_malloc().

Comment: If first example's assignment operation uses unaligned instruction, it will be slower. _mm_store_ps is aligned store isnt it? First example is similar to elementwise copy. Can you show disassembler output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiled with g++ at optimization level O3 the assembly code of the inner loop (using `objdump -d`) are

```
20:   0f 28 04 07             movaps (%rdi,%rax,1),%xmm0
24:   0f 58 c1                addps  %xmm1,%xmm0
27:   0f 29 04 06             movaps %xmm0,(%rsi,%rax,1)
2b:   48 83 c0 10             add    $0x10,%rax
2f:   48 39 d0                cmp    %rdx,%rax
32:   75 ec                   jne    20 <_Z5f_ssePfS_j+0x20>
```

and

```
10:   0f 28 04 07             movaps (%rdi,%rax,1),%xmm0
14:   83 c1 04                add    $0x4,%ecx
17:   0f 58 c1                addps  %xmm1,%xmm0
1a:   0f 29 04 06             movaps %xmm0,(%rsi,%rax,1)
1e:   48 83 c0 10             add    $0x10,%rax
22:   39 ca                   cmp    %ecx,%edx
24:   77 ea                   ja     10 <_Z5f_ssePfS_j+0x10>
```

They are pretty similar. In the first g++ manage to use only one counter (only one `add` instruction). So I guess its better.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled both of your samples with g++ -O2, and the main difference I found was that the value in `edx` (n) is used differently, which leads to slightly different code.

First function:

```
0000000000000000 <_Z6f_sse2PfS_j>:
   0:   c1 ea 02                shr    $0x2,%edx      # loop_size = n / 4. 
   3:   85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
   5:   74 2d                   je     34 <_Z6f_sse2PfS_j+0x34>
   7:   83 ea 01                sub    $0x1,%edx
   a:   0f 28 0d 00 00 00 00    movaps 0x0(%rip),%xmm1        # 11 <_Z6f_sse2PfS_j+0x11>
  11:   48 83 c2 01             add    $0x1,%rdx
  15:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  17:   48 c1 e2 04             shl    $0x4,%rdx             // Adjust for loop size vs. index. 
  1b:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  20:   0f 28 04 07             movaps (%rdi,%rax,1),%xmm0
  24:   0f 58 c1                addps  %xmm1,%xmm0
  27:   0f 29 04 06             movaps %xmm0,(%rsi,%rax,1)
  2b:   48 83 c0 10             add    $0x10,%rax
  2f:   48 39 d0                cmp    %rdx,%rax
  32:   75 ec                   jne    20 <_Z6f_sse2PfS_j+0x20>
  34:   f3 c3                   repz retq
```

Second function:

```
0000000000000000 <_Z5f_ssePfS_j>:
   0:   85 d2                   test   %edx,%edx
   2:   74 22                   je     26 <_Z5f_ssePfS_j+0x26>
   4:   0f 28 0d 00 00 00 00    movaps 0x0(%rip),%xmm1        # b <_Z5f_ssePfS_j+0xb>
   b:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
   d:   31 c9                   xor    %ecx,%ecx
   f:   90                      nop
  10:   0f 28 04 07             movaps (%rdi,%rax,1),%xmm0
  14:   83 c1 04                add    $0x4,%ecx
  17:   0f 58 c1                addps  %xmm1,%xmm0
  1a:   0f 29 04 06             movaps %xmm0,(%rsi,%rax,1)
  1e:   48 83 c0 10             add    $0x10,%rax
  22:   39 ca                   cmp    %ecx,%edx
  24:   77 ea                   ja     10 <_Z5f_ssePfS_j+0x10>
  26:   f3 c3                   repz retq
```

I also looked at the code generated, and came up with this:

```
void f_sse2(float *input, float *output, unsigned int n)
{
    __m128 *end = reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(&input[n]);
   __m128 *input_sse = reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(input);//Input intermediate pointer
   __m128 *output_sse = reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(output);//Output intermediate pointer
   __m128 s = _mm_set1_ps(0.1f);
   while(input_sse < end)
      *output_sse++ = _mm_add_ps(*input_sse++, s);
}
```

which generates this code:

```
0000000000000000 <_Z6f_sse2PfS_j>:
   0:   89 d2                   mov    %edx,%edx
   2:   48 8d 04 97             lea    (%rdi,%rdx,4),%rax
   6:   48 39 c7                cmp    %rax,%rdi
   9:   73 23                   jae    2e <_Z6f_sse2PfS_j+0x2e>
   b:   0f 28 0d 00 00 00 00    movaps 0x0(%rip),%xmm1        # 12 <_Z6f_sse2PfS_j+0x12>
  12:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  18:   0f 28 07                movaps (%rdi),%xmm0
  1b:   48 83 c7 10             add    $0x10,%rdi
  1f:   0f 58 c1                addps  %xmm1,%xmm0
  22:   0f 29 06                movaps %xmm0,(%rsi)
  25:   48 83 c6 10             add    $0x10,%rsi
  29:   48 39 f8                cmp    %rdi,%rax
  2c:   77 ea                   ja     18 <_Z6f_sse2PfS_j+0x18>
  2e:   f3 c3                   repz retq
```

Which I think may be a tiny bit more efficient, but probably not worth changing it for. But it gave me something to do for 15 minutes.