# Register's shortage using SSE intrinsics

Tags: c++, memory, sse, cpu-registers

In this post [SSE load/store memory transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625180/sse-load-store-memory-transactions) I asked about differences between explicit register-memory transactions and intermediate pointers. In practice, intermediate pointers showed slightly higher performance, however, it is unclear what is intermediate pointer in terms of hardware? If pointer was created, does it mean that some registers also occupied, or register's call occurs during some SSE operation (_mm_mul, for example)?

Let's consider the example:

```
struct sse_simple
{
    sse_simple(unsigned int InputLength):
        Len(InputLength/4),
        input1((float*)_mm_malloc((float *)_mm_malloc(cast_sz*sizeof(float), 16))),
        input2((float*)_mm_malloc((float *)_mm_malloc(cast_sz*sizeof(float), 16))),
        output((float*)_mm_malloc((float *)_mm_malloc(cast_sz*sizeof(float), 16))),
        inp1_sse(reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(input1)),
        inp1_sse(reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(input2)),
        output_sse(reinterpret_cast<__m128*>(output))
    {}

    ~sse_simple()
    {
        _mm_free(input1);
        _mm_free(input2);
        _mm_free(output);
    }

    void func()
    {
        for(auto i=0; i<Len; ++i)
            output_sse[i] = _mm_mul(inp1_sse[i], inp2_sse[i]);
    }

    float *input1;
    float *input2;
    float *output; 

    __m128 *inp1_sse;
    __m128 *inp2_sse;
    __m128 *output_sse;

    unsigned int Len;
};
```

In example above intermediate pointers inp1_sse, inp2_sse and output_sse creates once, in constructor. If I replicate a large amount of sse_simple objects (e.g. 50 000 and more), could this lead to a shortage of registers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, registers are small memories which are close (meaning access is very fast) to the computational units. The compiler try to use them at most as possible to speed up computation, but when it can't it uses memory. Since the amount of memory stored in register is small, usually register are only used as temporaries during computation. Most of the time everything ends up to be stored in memory, except for temporary variable such as loop indexes... So shortage of register only slow down computation.

During computation, pointer are stored in general purpose register (GPR) whether they point on float, vector or whatever, whereas vectors `__m128` are stored in specific register.

So in you example the tree arrays will be stored in memory and the line

```
output_sse[i] = _mm_mul(inp1_sse[i], inp2_sse[i]);
```

is compiled as:

```
movaps -0x30(%rbp),%xmm0    # load inp1_sse[i] in register %xmm0
movaps -0x20(%rbp),%xmm1    # load inp2_sse[i] in register %xmm1
mulps  %xmm1,%xmm0          # perform the multiplication the result is stored in %xmm0
movaps %xmm0,(%rdx)         # store the result in memory
```

As you can see pointer are stored using registers `%rbp` and `%rdx`.